# Guidance with impala installation mac os

Tags: macos, hadoop, cloudera, impala, bigdata

The official impala installation includes apt-get for installing impala on linux systems, is there any way i can brew(or any other way) impala packages on mac, running yosemite and CDH 5.1.1.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the work to get Impala to [build and run on OS X](https://issues.cloudera.org/browse/IMPALA-2761) and to [install with Homebrew](https://issues.cloudera.org/browse/IMPALA-1409) on the Cloudera JIRA (though I'm sure these issues will migrate to the Apache JIRA, as Impala was [recently contributed](https://vision.cloudera.com/cloudera-submitting-impala-and-kudu-to-the-apache-incubator/) to the Apache Incubator).